# Sublime Text 2 command Ctrl+Shift+/ is override in ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, sublime-text

I use Sublime Text 2 and because I use to work in different computer I don't like to change the default setting, so I note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> is overridden in ubuntu but I don't know where to verify this.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> is for block comments and is very handy, have any of you fixed this?

Update, I just notice something that is even wrong.

My laptop has num keyboard, that includes in it the <kbd>/</kbd> but sublime do nothing when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (in the num pad), but works with the / in my 7, I mean, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>

I'm totally lost now

Comment: Is override by which action? In other words, what does it happens when you press Ctrl+Shift+/ ?

Comment: That is the weird thing, at least in my computer, nothing happens... nohing... if I change it to ctrl+shift+alt+/ ... neither happen and also does work...

Comment: BUt if a change to lets say ctrl+shift+c... then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct code for the numpad / is `keypad_divide`. You should be able to use it by changing the user keybindings as follow:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
]
```

Also, you seem to have an ISO keyboard, if you want to use the `7/` key for comments you have to change your keybindings like so:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
]
```

Comment: How did you know the correct code was `keypad_divide`? Where can one look these up?